# Add transition to dynamically created object

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I would like to assign a transition to a dynamically created button, but it didn't happen.

```
Button btn = new Button();
Grid.SetRow(btn, j);
Grid.SetColumn(btn, i);
btn.Transitions.Add(new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.RepositionThemeTransition());                    
myGrig.Children.Add(btn);
```

I get a runtime errror, a NullReference exception, on the btn.Transition... line.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this..

```
     Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Transitions = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.TransitionCollection();
        Grid.SetRow(btn, j);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn, i);
        btn.Transitions.Add(new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.RepositionThemeTransition());                    
        myGrig.Children.Add(btn);
```